# How can I set .gitignore to ignore all .jars but not in the expected folder

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a project structure like this:

```
/proj/a/file.jar
/proj/a/1/file.jar
/proj/b/file.jar
/proj/b/1/file.jar
/proj/b/2/1/file.jar
/proj/c/file.jar
/proj/c/1/file.jar
/proj/c/2/1/file.jar
```

etc.

I'm trying to ignore all jar files except those in **c** folder and all nested ones. How should I set this in .gitignore?

```
*.jar
!c/*.jar
```

doesn't work. This too:

```
*.jar
!c/*/*.jar
```

and this:

```
*.jar
!/proj/c/*/*.jar
```

and this:

```
*.jar
!/proj/c/**/*.jar
```

Am I miss something?

Comment: It should work: https://gist.github.com/92a07fbe1f00ae9b5169

Comment: ThiefMaster, thanks, it works. But in the real project the level of nesting is diferent from file to file. Should I write all possible levels to gitignore, like "/proj/c/*/*.jar", "/proj/c/*/*/*.jar", "/proj/c/*/*/*/*.jar" and so on? Something like "/proj/c/**/*.jar" does not work. :( I've edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Yeah, if `**` is not supported you need to write each level of nesting separately. Or you could create separate .gitignore files in the subdirectories which just contain `!*.jar`.

Comment: ThiefMaster, seems like ** absolutely doesn't work (both Win7 and Linux systems). So I've created additional .gitignore with "!*.jar" in my c folder. It works, so I can accept your answer, but it should be an answer. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git does not support a `**`-style wildcard so you can either use full paths (i.e. `/whatever/*/*/*.jar` etc.) for to reflect the correct amounts of directory levels or you can simply put `.gitignore` files containing `!*.jar` inside the folders where you want to unignore JAR files.

Comment: "simply put .gitignore files containing !*.jar inside the folders where you want to unignore JAR files."  this is nicer than polluting a top-level .gitignore

Comment: Adding the line `!/path/to/my.jar`  _AFTER_  the `*.jar` entry in .gitignore made it work for me.   It does not work if the line `!/path/to/my.jar` appears before the `*.jar` line in the .gitignore file.  Order is important in the .gitignore file. Burnt my hands today.